# Print each line of a merged data frame in R

Tags: r

I am trying to merge the content of 2 text files and print the merged output using R. My code is given below:

```
setwd("C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator\\Desktop\\Test")
file_list <- list.files()


for (file in file_list){
  print(file)
  # create merged dataset if it does not exist
  if(!exists("dataset")){
    dataset <- read.table(file, header=TRUE, sep="\t")
  }
  # else, append to it
  if(exists("dataset")){
    temp_dataset <-read.table(file, header=TRUE, sep="\t")
    dataset <- rbind(dataset,temp_dataset)
    rm(temp_dataset)
  }
}
dataset
```

There are 2 text files in the "Test" folder - file1.txt, and file2.txt. file1.txt has the line ABC, and file2.txt DEF. However, when running the script, only ABC is being printed, and not DEF. I cannot figure out why. I am new to R scripting, and hence might be making basic errors. Please help.

Comment: How do you expect this to work if each file has one line? This is interpreted as the header since you have `header = T` so your datasets contain no rows. Also, what @JeremyS says is right, because if you have more than 2 files, and they are long, `rbind`ing many times will be super-slow. So read-in each one at a time in a list, and then `rbind` the list in one call. Finally, for `rbind` to work, don't forget that your data sets must all have the same header!

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my mistake. I removed the header and used lapply and it worked!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or use `rbindlist` from `data.table`

```
 library(data.table)
 file_list <- list.files() #2 rows per files
  rbindlist(lapply(file_list, fread))
 #  A  B  C
 # 1: 4 12 18
 # 2: 3  5  6
 # 3: 4 14 25
 # 4: 3 13 28
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need that loop, you can just lapply across your files then rbind the resulting list of data.frames into a single one

```
file_list <- list.files()
table_list <- lapply(file_list, read.delim)
Single_table <- do.call(rbind, table_list)
```